# Building Inno Setup installer for MSI files

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I'm building a deployment for a work environment, and doing it with Inno Setup. I wrap the other installers in one Inno-exe-File. It's working fine with other exe installers, but fails when it comes to MSI installers.

I don't know if there is any general problem, but it completely ignores my file association with the MSI exe (it works fine in Explorer, the association is ok).

Any ideas ? Probably there is some general problem..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks to ewall I found this working for me:

Use a bat file for execution of all your MSIs, where you call each with full path, this way:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Programme\mySetup\tmp\InstallernameX" /qb-
```

Comment: Why would you replace `%windir%` with a hard-coded path to the Windows system directory which could fail on any other system than yours?

Answer (score 8):

Have the script launch Windows Installer just by executing the .MSI file will not work--the lookup of the default action to do when you open a file is done by the shell, but not automagically done by programs trying to launch things.

But the answer is simple: you just need to provide the [msiexec.exe command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28WS.10%29.aspx) to launch them, something like this:

```
%windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /i <your_msi_filename> /qb-
```